# Clojure dosync inside future vs future inside dosync

Tags: clojure, stm

I have the following piece of code

```
(def number (ref 0))

(dosync (future (alter number inc)))  ; A
(future (dosync (alter number inc)))  ; B
```

The 2nd one succeeds, but the first one fails with `no transaction is running`. But it is wrapped inside a dosync right?

Does clojure remember opening of transactions based on which thread it was created in ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  The whole purpose of `dosync` is to begin a transaction in the current thread. The `future` runs its code in a new thread, so the `alter` in case A is not inside of a `dosync` for its thread.

For case B, the `alter` and `dosync` are both in the same (new) thread, so there is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple reasons this doesn't work. As Alan Thompson writes, transactions are homed to a single thread, and so when you create a new thread you lose your transaction.

Another problem is the dynamic scope of `dosync`. The same problem would arise if you wrote

```
((dosync #(alter number inc)))
```

Here we create a function inside of the `dosync` scope, and let that function be the result of the `dosync`. Then we call the function from outside of the `dosync` block, but of course the transaction is no longer running.

That's very similar to what you're doing with `future`: `future` creates a function and then executes it on a new thread, returning a handle you can use to inspect the progress of that thread. Even if cross-thread transactions were allowed, you would have a race condition here: does the `dosync` block close its transaction before or after the `alter` call in the `future` is executed?